# Swift : Parse PFQueryTableViewController - numberOfRowsInSection when PFObject is Array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am new with Swift and Parse.
I am using a PFQueryTableViewController , where the object I want to present is an Array. The table view now shows the first element of the Array with indexPath.row = 0.
But when I override the PFQueryTableViewController and return 3 , I get an error. 
If the count was working , is it ok to pass from cellForRowAtIndexPath the count of "friends" array with a global variable?

queryForTable:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        var result = query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        return result
    }
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! PFTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        if let friends = object?["friends"] as? NSArray {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = friends[indexPath.row] as? String
        }
        return cell
    }
```

// optional numberOfRowsInSection

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a best practice to have your numberOfRowsInSection return the count of the collection you are displaying. See below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentUser!.friends?.count
}
```

If your tableView is only showing the "friends" of one user at a time, then you should have a class variable for the PFUser you are viewing friends for. Your tableView numberOfRowsInSection should be as above. If you do that, your code:

```
if let friends = object?["friends"] as? NSArray {
     cell?.textLabel?.text = friends[indexPath.row] as? String
}
```

simply becomes:

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = currentUser!.friends[indexPath.row] as? String
```

Comment: Well , there is not a .friend to currentUser because the result are in a PFQuery , but not locally. I manage to make it work using a default UITableViewController without queryForTable( ).